# sum function issue

Tags: python, pandas

i am not good at python right now, i have been trying something for a long time but i couldn't do, i want to sum values in a column but i had an error like this:

```
<lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'
```

These are codes:

```
threshold = sum(data2.budget)/len(data2.budget)
print(threshold)
data2["budget_level"] = ["high" if i > threshold else "low" for i in data2.budget]
data2.loc[:10,["budget_level","budget"]]
```

This is all alert:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-240-f1303a50f5b0> in <module>
----> 1 threshold = sum(data2.budget)/len(data2.budget)
      2 print(threshold)
      3 data2["budget_level"] = ["high" if i > threshold else "low" for i in data.budget]
      4 data2.loc[:10,["budget_level","budget"]]

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'
```

I am writing this code from a source, but this guy hadn't have an error alert but i had. What can i do? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried printing `data2.budget` ?

Comment: check if it is `data2.budget` or something else

Comment: Yes, i have tried and it works.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Also, I think you're just looking for the average/mean of a column, in which case you can simply do `df['budget'].mean()`.

Comment: you are right but i tried a different way, i have a homework and i thought that i need to do it as how my teacher show me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pd.Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) and check threshold with [`pd.Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html). Then we use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to get `high` or `low` instead `True` or `False` in `np.array` that we  assign to `data2["budget_level"]`

```
threshold = data2['budget'].sum()/len(data2)

data2["budget_level"] = np.where(data2['budget'].gt(threshold),'high','low')
# if you are really checking data and not data2
#data2["budget_level"] = np.where(data['budget'].gt(threshold),'high','low')
```

or

```
data2["budget_level"] = data2['budget'].gt(threshold).map({True:'high',False:'low'})
```

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5]})
import numpy as np
threshold = 2
df['B'] = np.where(df['A'].gt(threshold),'high','low')
print(df)
   A     B
0  1   low
1  2   low
2  3  high
3  4  high
4  5  high
```

Comment: I am trying this...

Comment: what do you obtain?

Comment: the root of error is sum function, when i write about sum the error alert comes. i tried.

Comment: what is output of  `data2['budget'].sum() / len(data2)`? please show error

Comment: I took this error. AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'div'

Comment: What should i ?

Comment: try : `data2['budget'].sum() / len(data2)`

Comment: I tried and i didn't have error it works. I guess it's correct. i m not sure because there are 4800 rows :)

Comment: if this is correct, I was simply trying to use a panda series method applied to a float value of type `numpy.array 64`:)

Comment: Thank you very much, i m sorry i am a novice and i took your time

Comment: don't worry you are welcome:) I have added an example how `np.where` works, solution with `map` is similar

Comment: uh of course :) thanks again.

Comment: i couldn't vote up, less than 15 rep. :)

Comment: If you intend to make the second example runnable/reproducible, you're missing the Pandas import, and the NumPy import should go at the top.